# Is it ok to use the message id as a start value in AES Counter Mode

Tags: aes

I want to encrypt multiple messages using AES in Counter mode with the same key. Would it be secure enough to use the id of each message as the start value for the counter? The message ids are more or less consecutive.

Comment: Will there **never** be a key counter pair reused? If a pair may be resized the security is lost.

Comment: Yes the key-counter pairs will be unique and never reused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The weakness is that you are exposing part of the data if there message ID is part of the encrypted data and that can be used as a crib in a brute force attack on the key.

If the key is a random byte sequence a brute force attack against a 128-bit or larger AES key impractical, read not possible.

If the key is weak such as a password or derived from a password with a weak method a brute force attack on the password is possible. Simple cryptographic hash methods are weak, PBKDF2 with a suitable iteration count is strong.

Comment: >The weakness is that you are exposing part of the encrypted data.  Do you mean the message id ? Because only the body of the message is encrypted not the id. And as far as I understand it I would have to send the counter either way.

Comment: @ACB Yes, corrected. If the message ID is not part of the encrypted data there is no problem.